# Parse JSON array into different Object using Reduce

Tags: javascript, json

I have an script that is receiving some JSON and then I am parsing it out using `reduce`.  I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it.

JSON

```
 var request = {
    "operation":"rate_request",
    // JSON removed to make more readable. 
    "freight":
    {
        "items":
        // here is the array I am targeting
        [{
            "item":"7205",
            "qty":10,
            "units":10,
            "weight":"19.0000",
            "paint_eligible":false
        },
        {
            "item":"7677",
            "qty":10,
            "units":4,
            "weight":"5.0000",
            "paint_eligible":false
        }],
    // more JSON removed
}
```

Here is function to parse out and then loop through:

```
function parseItems(json){
    var resultsReduce = new Object()
    var itemKeys = ['item','qty', 'units','weight', 'paint_eligable']
    itemKeys.forEach(function(item){  
        if (item){
            resultsReduce[item] = json.freight.items.reduce(function(array, object) {
                   return array.concat(object[item])
            }, [])
        }
    })
    var itemXML = ''

    for(var i = 0; i < resultsReduce.item.length; i++){
        var weight = Number(resultsReduce['weight'][i])
        var qty = Number(resultsReduce['qty'][i])
        var units = Number(resultsReduce['units'][i])
        itemXML += '<LineItem>'
                + '<PieceCount>' + units * qty + '</PieceCount>'
                + '<NetWeight UOM="Lb">' + weight * qty + '</NetWeight>'
                +'<GrossWeight UOM="Lb">' + weight * qty + '</GrossWeight>'
                + '<FreightClassification>' + '50' + '</FreightClassification>'
                +'</LineItem>'
    }
    return itemXML
}
```

The `parseItems` function turn the JSON into an object with arrays:

```
  {
 "item": [7205,7677],
 "qty": [10,10],
 "units": [10,4],
 "weight": ["19.0000","5.0000"],
 "paint_eligible": [false, false]
 }
```

Then the function loops through the object (manually by targeting the keys) and loops through the loop of the array. Like I mentioned, I am sure it can be more elegant. Any thoughts on how you would make it cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled with a single `Array.prototype.forEach` loop. Consider the following:

```
function parseItems(json){
  var output = '';
  json.freight.items.forEach(function (item) {
    output += `
      <LineItem>
        <PieceCount>${item.units * item.qty}</PieceCount>
        <NetWeight UOM="Lb">${item.weight * item.qty}</NetWeight>
        <GrossWeight UOM="Lb">${item.weight * item.qty}</GrossWeight>
        <FreightClassification>50</FreightClassification>
      </LineItem>`;
  });

  return output;
}
```

No need to iterate over everything repeatedly for this.

Edit: [Made a fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/xtvs75bf/)

Comment: Note I used string interpolation syntax since I think it looks cleaner. Browser compatibility may limit your ability to use it.